# CustomTableView never updates

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

This code suppose to get data from JSON object then update the table's rows with it,so i have used (tableView.reloaddata) but it doesn't work.

```
class history: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    var rec = [recs]()
    var delegate2 : historyViewControllerProtocol!
    var ID2 = [String]()
    var Amount2 = [String]()
    var Desc2 = [String]()
    var records:String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        reciptshistory(){ (boolValue) -> () in
            self.Loaddata()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
                   }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func reciptshistory(completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool)->())
    {

        var Buffer : String
        Buffer = "userID=" + userID

        print("intial///////////////////" + Buffer + "//////////////End")

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://nh75.com.kw/old-soon/Paynet/recipthistory.php")!
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

        let data = Buffer.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let task = session.uploadTask(with: request as URLRequest, from: data, completionHandler:
            {(data,response,error) in


                guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
                    print("error")
                    return
                }

                let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
                print(dataString as Any)
                self.records = dataString!;


                if(self.records == "X")
                {
                    print("No records");
                    completion (true)

                } else {
                    print (dataString! )
                    do {
                        // let data = dataString?.data(using: .utf8)
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                        if let result = json["result"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                            for blog in result {
                                if let iD = blog["id"] as? String {
                                    if let amount = blog["Amount"] as? String {
                                        if let desc = blog["Desc"] as? String {
                                            self.ID2.append(iD)
                                            self.Amount2.append(amount)
                                            self.Desc2.append(desc)
                                            //recipt.text = self.ID
                                            //print(ID , Amount , Desc)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            completion (true)
                        }
                    }catch {
                        print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
                    }
                }





        }


        );
        task.resume()
    }


    func Loaddata()
    {
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
     if(self.records == "X")
     {

                let alert = UIAlertController(
                    title: "No Records found",
                    message: "No records found for you",
                    preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (test) -> Void in
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }))

                self.present(
                    alert,
                    animated: true,
                    completion: nil)




     }else{

        for L in 0..<self.ID2.count{
                self.rec += [recs(reciptsnum: self.ID2[L] , amount:self.Amount2[L] , descript: self.Desc2[L])!]
        }
        }
        }
        }





    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rec.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        let cellIdentifier = "RecTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RecTableViewCell
        // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.

        let recc = rec[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.reciptnum.text = recc.reciptsnum
        cell.Amount.text = recc.amount
        cell.descript.text = recc.descript
        return cell

    }
```

Everytime i run the app , the Custom tableview is empty ,please advice...
[here is a screenshot of the app running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcNIN.png)

Comment: put reloadTable in main thread as DispatchQueue.main.async { ReloadTableHere...}

Comment: woooow Man you are amazing....it worked.....Thanks alot
@Gagan_iOS

Comment: welcome :)  Remember always performs any UI update on mainthread if u r working inside secondary thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have updated the code as @Gagan_IOS advised and it worked pretty fine .....

```
reciptshistory(){ (boolValue) -> () in
    self.Loaddata()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your controller is not hooked up to your table as delegate and data source. If you set it up in the storyboard as 'UITableViewController' rather than 'UIViewController' (and subclass 'history' as UITableViewController) it should automatically connect.

You can also connect in code with:

tableView.delegate=self
tableView.datasource=self

but you'll still probably have to subclass as UITableViewController and not UIViewController.

Comment: but i have noted that if i let the view to load for 3mins ...the data will appear !!!

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try:

Set TableView Delegate and Data Source to self

Set Cell reuse identifier on Storyboard

Make sure that the data is being pulled correctly and the array is not empty when table is being reloaded

Comment: i pretty sure i have done that all, but i have noted that if i let the view to load for 3mins ...the data will appear !!!